# Concat array into one array (JS or Lodash)

Tags: javascript, lodash

Input:

```
var array1 = ["12346","12347\n12348","12349"];
```

Steps:

> Replace `\n` with `','` and Add into list.

Output:

```
var array2 = ["12346","12347","12348","12349"];
```

I tried below logic but not reach to output. Looks like something is missing.

```
var array2 = [];

_.forEach(array1, function (item) {               
       var splitData = _.replace(item, /\s+/g, ',').split(',').join();
       array2.push(splitData);
});
```

Output of my code:

```
["12346","12347,12348","12349"]
```

Answer (score 10):

You could join it with newline `'\n'` and split it by newline for the result.

```js
var array= ["12346", "12347\n12348", "12349"],
    result = array.join('\n').split('\n');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: great idea best use  :)

Comment: Superb... Solution is working for me... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can we avoid duplicates? if input having some duplicates like `var array= ["12346", "12347\n12348", "12349", "12348" ]`

Comment: then you need some method like `array = [...(new Set(array))]`, or an equivalent in ES5

Comment: @AnandSomani You can refer following post to remove duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: Found answer : `_.uniqWith(array.join().replace(/\n/g, ',').split(','),_.isEqual);`

Comment: An interesting and helpful approach. Have another Nice Answer badge.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using lodash, applying [`flatmap`](https://lodash.com/docs#flatMap) would be the simplest way:

```js
var array1 = ["12346", "12347\n12348", "12349"];
var array2 = _.flatMap(array1, (e) => e.split('\n'));

console.log(array2);
//=> ["12346", "12347", "12348", "12349"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate to @Nina's answer would be to use `Array.push.apply` with `string.split(/\n/)`

```js
var array= ["12346","12347\n12348","12349"];
var result = []

array.forEach(function(item){
   result.push.apply(result, item.split(/\n/))
})

console.log(result);
```